# React Navigation Event on Same screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am currently using "didFocus" event in React Navigation which works fine for most of my cases. I am having issue when the screen is same and this event doesn't trigger.

Is there an event in React Navigation that occurs when the user is on same screen upon navigation?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want to know if there is an event that triggers on navigation to same route. I want to refetch the data when that event triggers which I am currently achieving using a callback function. I want to skip passing that call back function.

Comment: I am also facing this issue, were you ever able to find a solution for this @gamingumar?

Comment: @saadq the workaround I found was to attach a custom event to tabBarOnPress. When screen mounts I attach a method to navigation props using navigation.setParams(). In onTabPress of defaultNavigationOptions I was able to access that method in navigation.state.routes[0].params

Answer (score 0):

When a route rerenders (for example if the route params change) it would trigger `componentDidRecieveProps`